# Arguments instead of Props in React Functional Component

Tags: reactjs, arguments, jsx, react-functional-component

Is this function correct React Functional Component? Or why should I use `props` object?

```
function StyledLabel(value, cssClass){
   return <span className={cssClass}>{value}</span>
}
```

Only difference I see is in calling this function:

```
<App>
   {StyledLabel(value, cssClass)}
</App>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function StyledLabel(value, cssClass){
   return <span className={cssClass}>{value}</span>
}
```

being used like

```
{StyledLabel(value, cssClass)}
```

isn't a traditional functional component but a function that returns JSX.

If you follow such a syntax, you won't be able to leverage some functionalities of a functional component such as using `React.memo`.

Although you can still use hooks within the functional component.

The other drawback of using such a syntax is that you cannot easily add children components to StyledLabel like you do with the following syntax

```
<StyledLabel>
    <SomeChild/>
</StyledLabel>
```

Although internally React too invokes the function by calling it and JSX render is a just a `Syntactic Sugar` that uses `React.createElement` to transpile it but it provides you with a way to make the component a part of the Virtual DOM instead of its return value being part of virtual dom

Answer (score 5):

Function Component is a function which returns `JSX` element.

That's a **Function Component** which **invoked** as a normal function.

---

But in this case is hasn't invoked with `React.createElement`.

Because JSX is [syntactic sugar](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Syntactic_sugar#:~:text=In%20computer%20science%2C%20syntactic%20sugar,style%20that%20some%20may%20prefer.) for `React.createElement`, you need to invoke the function with JSX syntax like so:

```
function StyledLabel({ value, cssClass }) {
  return <span className={cssClass}>{value}</span>;
}

<App>
  <StyledLabel value={value} cssClass={cssClass} />
</App>
```

Without invoking `React.createElement`, React won't be aware of the component (for state updates, diffing algorithm etc.), as it will be just a normal function call.

Yet another major problem is the function arguments:

```
// Not function StyledLabel(value, cssClass)
function StyledLabel(props)
```

`React.createElement` accepts a single argument which is the component's props.

- [`React.createElement` API](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement)

```
React.createElement(
  type,
  [props],
  [...children]
)
```