# Can you pass more than one arguments to Function Component in React? If yes than how?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

there I am very new to React lib.

I don't know if we can use other arguments rather than props in React.
How to pass and use this extra parameter in React Function Component.

```
export function DisplayName(props, extra) {
  // How can I use extra in this function?
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello {props.name}</h1>
      <p>Extra arguments </p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Functional components are used like `<DisplayName prop1={1} prop2={blah} />` etc. Just put everything in a prop and you can access it via `props.` (There's no need or way to add more params)

Comment: How would you _use_ this component? All arguments passed to the component are stored in `props`.

Comment: See [Arguments instead of Props in React Functional Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62468665/arguments-instead-of-props-in-react-functional-component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, in your top component you need to define two props. Like;

```
<DisplayName name={'Jay Bansod'} extra={''} />
```

And you can use them in two way.

**1:** Use a parameter on your under component function. This parameter includes all props. You can use them like

```
  export function DisplayName(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <p> First Props : {props.name} </p>
      <p> Second Props : {props.extra}  </p>
    </>
  );
}
```

**2:** In other way; you can create a object for the parameter in your under component

```
  export function DisplayName({name,extra}) {
  return (
    <>
      <p> First Props : {name} </p>
      <p> Second Props : {extra}  </p>
    </>
  );
}
```